# Relation between $\Delta \subset PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ and $\pi_1(S)$ where $S \cong \mathbb{H^2}/\Delta$.

Tags: general-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose $S \cong \mathbb{H^2}/\Delta$ where $\Delta$ is a discrete subgroup of $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$

I am told that $\Delta \subset PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is canonically isomorphic to $\pi_1(S)$.

I am probably missing a lot of theory, as I don't understand why this is. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's because $\mathbb H^2$ is simply connected and $\mathbb H^2 \to S$ is a covering map. (Just like $\mathbb S^1 = \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, and $\pi_1(\mathbb S^1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$). For a reference, you can see the book "introduction to topological manifold" by J.M. Lee. There is a chapter on covering spaces.

Comment: Is this corollary 11.31? That each fibre of $q : E \mapsto X $has the same cardinality as the fundamental group of $X$? (Where $q$ is a covering map and $E$ is simply connected?

This would just talk about isomorphic as sets, I thought they may have been isomorphic as groups?

Comment: It's an isomorphism as groups. I do not have the book so I cannot tell how this is stated in the book. But the proof is roughly the following: Let $E$ be a fiber of $x_0\in S$. Every points in the fiber corresponds to a unqiue elements in $\Delta$. Then you can also think of $\Delta = E$ (fix a base point $e_0 \in E$, then there is a unique $g\in \Delta$ so taht $g(e_0)=e$). Now define a map $\Phi: E \to \pi_1(S, x_0)$ by: for all $e\in E$, $\Phi(e) = \pi(\gamma)$, where $\gamma$ is a curve in $\mathbb H$ connecting $e_0$ and $e$. This map is an iso as groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is not true universally. For this to be true one must require that $\Delta$ is not only discrete, but that it acts freely, meaning that each nontrivial element of $\Delta$ has no fixed points in $\mathbb{H}^2$.

But second, as long as $\Delta$ is discrete and free, then this follows from the theory of covering spaces: the quotient map $f : \mathbb{H}^2 \to \mathbb{H}^2 / \Delta = S$ is a covering map, the domain $\mathbb{H}^2$ is simply connected so $f$ is a universal covering map, and the fundamental theorem of universal covering spaces has exactly the conclusion you want, namely that the group $\Delta$, which is the "deck transformation group" of the map $f$, is isomorphic to $\pi_1(S)$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Do you know where I can find the Fundamental Theorem of Universal Covering Spaces?

Comment: I recommend Munkres' "Topology". That theorem is only a very special case of a more general theory, which centers around the "Fundamental Theorem of Covering Spaces" that relates covering spaces to subgroups of the fundamental group. You'll also need the part of the theory which relates regular covering spaces and their deck transformation groups to normal subgroups of the fundamental group and their quotient groups.